# Using regex to retrieve link between special characters in a string

Tags: php, regex

I want to retrieve the link between (Ampersand)lt; and (Ampersand)gt; from the below string.

```
&lt;http://www.test.com&gt;
```

I then want to replace the above string with the link. The string is in a file so I'm using the following code to replace the string in the file:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
$contents = str_replace($id."\n", "", $contents);
if($count>0){
  file_put_contents($filename,$contents);
}
```

However I cant figure out the regex I need to do this, can anyone help? I'm able to select the whole string using this but not the link I need.

```
"\&[l][t]\;(.*?)\&[g][t]\;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without any regex using [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.trim.php) and [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php):

```
$s = '&lt;http://www.test.com&gt;';
$s = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($s), "<>");
echo $s; // => http://www.test.com
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/sRPbPz)

The `htmlspecialchars_decode` will convert the special HTML entities back to characters, and `trim` will remove `<` and `>` from the start and end of the string.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed got it working!

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution below thanks to Wiktors advice. Hopefully it can help someone else out!

```
function removeUnwantedSignsFromContact($path){
    $contents = file_get_contents($path);
    if(preg_match( '/\&[l][t]\;(.*?)\&[g][t]\;/', $contents, $match )){
      $filteredContact = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($match[0]), "<>");
      $contents = str_replace($match[0], $filteredContact, $contents);
      file_put_contents($path,$contents);
      return simplexml_load_file($path);
    }
}
```